# Multiply 2D Matrix with vector to span third dimension - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, multiplication, dimension

As I am trying to multiply a `m x n` Matrix with a `p-dimensional` vector, I am stumbling across some difficulties.

Trying to avoid for loops, here is what I am looking to achieve

```
enter code here
M = [1 2 3;                   p = [1;2;3]
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9]
```

I want to obtain a `3x3x3` matrix, where the slices in third dimension are simply the entries of `M` multiplied by the respective entry in `p`.

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) for a [`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) (no-loop) approach like so -

```
out = bsxfun(@times,M,permute(p(:),[3 2 1]))
```

You would end up with -

```
out(:,:,1) =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
out(:,:,2) =
     2     4     6
     8    10    12
    14    16    18
out(:,:,3) =
     3     6     9
    12    15    18
    21    24    27
```

---

With `matrix-multiplication` -

```
out = permute(reshape(reshape(M.',[],1)*p(:).',[size(M) numel(p)]),[2 1 3])
```

Comment: thank you very much. Could the summing up of the entries along the third dimension, thereby shrinking the dimension two 2 also be included in thus approach or is an extra line of cod advised?

Comment: @CarstenD Do `sum(out,3)` for that.

Comment: thanks a lot. Which of those two recommended approaches is more efficient though?

Comment: @CarstenD: If you want to sum along the third dimension, you shouldn't generate a 3D matrix at all. Just do `M*sum(p)`.

Comment: @CarstenD Yup, as  knedlsepp  said, if the only final output you need is sum along the third dimension after the elementwise multiplication, `M*sum(p)` should be efficient. But, if you need the 3D array too, I would think `bsxfun` based approach to be quite efficient.

Comment: @CarstenD If this post answered all your queries, consider accepting it.  Read more about accepting solutions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).