# Matlab: How to multiply 3-dimensional array with Vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, multiplication

Suppose I have an array M of dimension M = (3, 12, 9) and a vector C with 9 elements.

How do I efficiently multiply M with C so that

M(:,:,1) * C(1)
M(:,:,2) * C(2)

and so forth?

help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to perform scalar multiplication ? Because `M(:,:,1)` is a `3x12` matrix whereas `C(1)` is a single element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681196/3d-matrix-multiplication-with-vector

Comment: You asked the same question not 2 weeks ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276924 ???

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
bsxfun(@times,A,permute(C(:),[3 2 1]));
```

orginally answered by [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807960/bsxfun-implementation-in-matrix-multiplication)

Comment: I want to scale each individual 3,12 submatrix with the corresponding value in C.   @Santhan, I dont get how this is suppose to help... can you elaborate?

Comment: Edited. See the link mentioned.

Comment: Would be nice to mention the assumption that vector C is a row vector, or do `bsxfun(@times,A,permute(C(:).',[3 1 2]));` or `bsxfun(@times,A,permute(C(:),[3 2 1]));` without stating any assumption.

Comment: thanks a lot but here is a follow up question:   Suppose I have a matrix M = (3, 12, 4) and I want to transform it so that

    M = (12,12)

basically just concatenating the individual (3,12) submatrices under each other.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @CarstenD That "concatenating under each other" operation is also dealt with in that [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23808285/3293881) at the end of it.

Comment: @CarstenD see [reshape](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html?refresh=true)

Comment: @Divakar, I'm a begginer and didn't knew `anyVector(:)` will always return a column vector. Its great to know. Thanks once again for pointing and correcting :)